# Replace a list of words occuring in sentences in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with list of sentences in one column. Now i have a list of words and another list of replacement words as follows.

```
DF

Date       Sentences
9-Nov-16   nah, i got rid of them overyears ago i was only watching pbs by then anyway i have xfinity on demand+netflix on my 'puter
9-Nov-16   Omg Netflix is working on my Xfinity!
```

and so on

**List of Words**

```
words <- c("nah","'puter","Omg")
trans <- c("No","computer","Oh my God")
```

and so on.

Now i want to replace "Nah" with "No" , "'puter" with "computer", "Omg" with "Oh my God" and so on in the sentences present in the above dataframe. To achieve this i use the following code.

```
DF$Sentences<- str_replace_all( DF$Sentences, paste0("\\b",words,"\\b"), trans)
```

But this is not replacing the words in the sentence. Can someone tell me the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
DF$Sentences <- mgsub(words, trans, DF$Sentences)
```

---

Or in a `for` loop with `gsub`

```
for(j in seq_along(words)){
  DF$Sentences <- gsub(words[j], trans[j], DF$Sentences)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stri_replace_all_fixed` or the like from `stringi` with `vectorize_all=FALSE`, eg

```
stri_replace_all_fixed(DF[["Sentences"]], words,  trans, vectorize_all=FALSE)
```